# FCM Device group BadJsonFormat - properly formed json

Tags: json, http, erlang, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was flooded with a primitive json body for fcm:

```
 Body = mochijson2:encode([ {<<"operation">>, <<"create">>},{<<"notification_key_name">>, <<"console group">>},{<<"registration_ids">>, [<<"02aa6XXXX3c9b6d">>,<<"APA91bGtaXXXXXXXXXXXXoi4UH8vIdZk1X67A_9izpSFSHV3BXxdIwG">>]}]).
```

And send POST-request to create group according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group):

```
httpc:request(post, {Url, [{"Authorization", KeyApi}, {"project_id", ProjectId}], "application/json", Body},[{timeout, 5000}], []).
```

But I got error BadJsonFormat:

```
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",400,"Bad Request"},
     [{"cache-control","private, max-age=0"},
      {"date","Fri, 10 Mar 2017 16:19:37 GMT"},
      {"accept-ranges","none"},
      {"server","GSE"},
      {"vary","Accept-Encoding"},
      {"content-length","25"},
      {"content-type","application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
      {"expires","Fri, 10 Mar 2017 16:19:37 GMT"},
      {"x-content-type-options","nosniff"},
      {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
      {"x-xss-protection","1; mode=block"},
      {"alt-svc","quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34\""}],
     "{\"error\":\"BadJsonFormat\"}"}}
```

But `mochijson2:decode(Body)` works fine, and it looks like properly formed json, but I get the error BadJsonFormat anyway.

What was wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mochijson2:encode` doesn't return a string or a binary, but an iolist:

```
1>  Body = mochijson2:encode([ {<<"operation">>, <<"create">>},{<<"notification_key_name">>, <<"console group">>},{<<"registration_ids">>, [<<"02aa6XXXX3c9b6d">>,<<"APA91bGtaXXXXXXXXXXXXoi4UH8vIdZk1X67A_9izpSFSHV3BXxdIwG">>]}]).
[123,
 [34,<<"operation">>,34],
 58,
 [34,<<"create">>,34],
 44,
 [34,<<"notification_key_name">>,34],
 58,
 [34,<<"console group">>,34],
 44,
 [34,<<"registration_ids">>,34],
 58,
 [91,
  [34,<<"02aa6XXXX3c9b6d">>,34],
  44,
  [34,<<"APA91bGtaXXXXXXXXXXXXoi4UH8vIdZk1X67A_9izpSF"...>>,
   34],
  93],
 125]
```

There is nothing wrong with that, by itself. Using iolists instead of strings or binaries means that you don't have to create an expensive flat data structure, that you would just write to a file or a socket, after which you'd throw it away.  Function like `file:write_file` and `gen_tcp:send` handle iolists just as well as strings or binaries.

However, `httpc:request` doesn't!

Let's test that by starting a server on port 1111 with netcat in a shell:

```
$ nc -l 1111
```

And then make a request from the Erlang shell:

```
3> httpc:request(post, {"http://127.0.0.1:1111", [], "application/json", Body},[{timeout, 5000}], []).
```

The netcat server shows this output:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
content-length: 13
te:
host: 127.0.0.1:1111
connection: keep-alive

{"operation":"create",....
```

Note that the `content-length` is 13 instead of 159!  `httpc:request` is able to send the iolist, but it uses the function `length` instead of `iolist_size` to generate the `content-length` header, and as a result the server only considers the first 13 bytes of the JSON object, which is not valid JSON by itself.

The solution is to pass `iolist_to_binary(Body)` to `httpc:request` instead of just `Body`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Forgoted about that